# Identify duplicate records and identify unique record based on a series logic statements

Tags: database

I have a list of world cities and various columns of data. The original final was obtained from Natural Earth and then additional fields were added including a ID column. For various records, the same ID was assigned to multiple records. This was not an error, based on what I did to join the ID, this is exactly what should have happened.

Now, I want to select one record to keep for each ID. When doing this manually, I started with the "worldcity" column. If a city was a world city (worldcity = 1), I kept that record. If more than one city had a value of 1 for this column or all records had a value of 0, I moved on to the "Megacity" column.

If only one city was labeled as a megacity ("Megacity=1) then I kept that column. If more than one city had a value of one or all records with that ID had a value of 0 for megacity, I moved on to the scalerank value.

If one of the cities had a lower value for "scalerank" then all other cities, I kept that record. If there was no unique minimum for this value I moved on to the "labelrank" column. If one of the records had a lower "labelrank" value than all other records with the same ID, I chose to keep that record and delete all others. If they have the same scale rank as well, I flagged these records to be looked at later.

My question is: Is there a way to do this automatically using a series of logic statements? Could I run this spreadsheet through some kind of code to speed up the process.

I would potentially need to sort through thousands of records. Most values are not duplicates, but it's important to identify those that are duplicates.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: What is the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in a database that supports commom table expressions (CTE), then its this. I do see you mention spreadsheet though so are we talking non-database?

```
;with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by ID order by worldcity desc, megacity desc,scalerank,labelrank) as ranking 
    from cities
)
select ...blah...
from cte
where ranking=1
```